# VSCode update to the latest version and Vetur bug

Tags: visual-studio-code, vetur

After my VS code has been updated to the latest version for some reason my Vetur shows the code with a problem.
Only in IDE show the bug. The compilation is ok.

VSCode version: 1.47.2
Vetur version: 0.25.0

```
Type of property '$v' circularly references itself in mapped type 'ValidationProperties<AprovarModal>'.Vetur(2615)
```

[Image the Vetur bug on IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM3Ek.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue [related to TypeScript 3.9](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37597), which is now used with Vetur 0.25.0.

If your project is using a different TypeScript version, you can [tell Vetur to use the workspace dependencies](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/682#issuecomment-474971395).

For me this fixed the issue.